# How to combine Entity Framework and SQL Compact in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, sql-server-ce-4

I am using the MS Entity Framework and Visual Studio 2012 in combination with the SQL Server Express. Now I want to use the EF in combination with an SQL Server Compact Edition database.

*The design process will be model first.*

I created an SQL CE database file in VS and started the design with a database model. I can create the  .slqce file, containing the database schema definitions without any problems.

Actually my Problem is, that I can't find out how to execute this file on the database.

To test another approach, I created the database tables, columns... in the Server Explorer and used this to create an entity model. This worked well, but again, I don't know how to update the DB with changes, made inside the model.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox addin to create the database file and execute the script. You may need a modified template, as I describe here http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/02/fixing-entity-framework-designer.html

Comment: Your SQL Server Compact Toolbox is a great pice of Software. Thank you very much. But I have a problem. In my Installation some menu entries seem to be missing. Where could I find the Option to exceute entry in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: The template really seems to be broken. Thanks for the hint! Maybe I trusted an outdated or wrong blogentry. Is there actually another way to execute a .sqlce script than by using copy and paste from the file into the SQL Editor?

Comment: 1: Connect to the file in the Toolbox, 2: Open SQL Editor (Context menu) 3: Paste text, 4: Press Execute button in the editor